# Google App Script with jquery tablesorter not working

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, tablesorter

Just wondering whether we can have jquery plugin in Google App Script? I tried to write a simple html with table using jquery tablesorter but it is not working. The html renders the style but there is no tablesorter function within the table. When I click on the header, it suppose to sort the table but no action was perform when clicking on each header. I copy and paste the exact same codes into a .html and tested it on my wampserver and it works. My codes are below. Any advise please?

```
<html>

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can test it in the [caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com/)

Comment: is having external jquery plugin allow at all in GAS? i have gone to caja playground. Do I just load my URL and Cajole it to see if it works on this caja compiler?

Answer (score 0):

There are explicit limitations for jQuery plugins, but the Caja engine that the HtmlService uses may reject JavaScript libraries if they use unsafe operations. As mentioned in the comments, use the [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com/) to see if your HTML and JavaScript passes validation.